# There is anything wrong with this proof? Real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a real-valued continuous function. If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \bar{X}$.

Proof:

Given $a\in \bar{X}$, there exists $\{x_n\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a \in \bar{X}$. In other words, for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$n>n_0 \Rightarrow|x_n - a |<\epsilon,\ \forall \epsilon >0.$$
Since $x_n\in X$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(x_n)=0\ \forall x_n \in \{x_n\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset X$. By the hypothesis, $f$ is continuous, then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=0=f(a),$$
because it's continuous and $x_n\rightarrow a$, so $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(a).$

Note: I think it's all right, but it seems slopy. There's been a while since I left college. -.-'
I would appreciate any comments or corrections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work seems fine to me. As far as writing goes, there's no need to state the definition of convergence with $\epsilon$ and $n_0$, since it is never used. The crucial fact you used is that continuous functions take convergent sequences to convergent sequences. Here's how I would have written it:

Let $a \in \overline{X}$. Then there is $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq X$ such that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n = a$. Therefore $$f(a) = f\left(\lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n\right) \stackrel{(*)}{=} \lim_{n\to +\infty} f(x_n) \stackrel{(**)}{=} \lim_{n\to +\infty} 0 = 0,$$as required, where on $(*)$ we use continuity of $f$ and in $(**)$ that $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in X$.

Note that the way I have phrased things, I started with $f(a)$, had a chain of equalities, and ended up with $0$, without going around to piece parts of the argument together. This is just a writing tip, really.

Comment: Continuity is absolutely needed. Counter-example: $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=1$, $X = \Bbb R \setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Your proof is more elegant than mine and I liked it.